# How effective is diacutaneous fibrolysis to treat an epicondylopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, tendons

(1) presented some interesting results regarding the effectiveness of diacutaneous fibrolysis to treat subacromial impingement syndromes. How effective is diacutaneous fibrolysis to treat an epicondylopathy (i.e., tennis elbow or golfer elbow)?

This [registered trial](https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/show/NCT02343809) plans to look at lateral epicondylopathies but I wonder whether there have been other studies, since the trial registered two years and a half ago, and many clinical trials are never completed.

---

(1) López, Martín Eusebio Barra, Carlos López de Celis, Gabriela Fernández Jentsch, Laura Raya de Cárdenas, María Orosia Lucha López, and José Miguel Tricás Moreno. "Effectiveness of diacutaneous fibrolysis for the treatment of subacromial impingement syndrome: a randomised controlled trial." Manual therapy 18, no. 5 (2013): 418-424. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1356689X13000350 ; http://sci-hub.cc/10.1016/j.math.2013.02.006#

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### As effective as sham.

This one is a more clear "no" though it has been used often.
The most [relevant and thorough review](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.math.2015.08.011) was done by a Canadian group looking at a wide array of data.  If you get into the details and results (sorry I can't provide it past paywall, but I have access) you will note that subacromial impingement syndrome (SAIS) is particularly resistant to most forms clinical massage and similar muscle manipulations.

To quote actually quite directly from the abstract, which gets directly to your point:

> Diacutaneous fibrolysis (DF) or sham DF leads to similar outcomes in
> pain intensity for SAIS.

It's also worth noting that the actual findings in the [study you linked](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.math.2013.02.006) don't really support the conclusions the original authors made. Note that study, and others with SAIS were used in the review I linked above.